# unable to install therubyracer arm chromebook

Tags: ruby, therubyracer

Getting the below error after trying to install therubyracer gem.

Not sure why it's complaining about v8 when i have the gem downloaded already.

I had original troubles installing libv8 but then manage to install with --system-v8 flags, but now its rubyracer complaining.

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/glenn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/glenn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
    --with-v8-dir
    --without-v8-dir
    --with-v8-include
    --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
    --with-v8-lib
    --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/
/home/glenn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': You have chosen to use the version of V8 found on your system (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
and *not* the one that is bundle with the libv8 rubygem. However,
it could not be located. please make sure you have a version of
v8 that is compatible with 3.11.8.17 installed. You may
need to special --with-v8-dir options if it is in a non-standard
location

thanks,
The Mgmt

    from /home/glenn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
    from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /home/glenn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/therubyracer-0.11.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/glenn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/therubyracer-0.11.4/ext/v8/gem_make.out
```

Comment: I believe currently it is not available with the Chrome OS as it is not even available for windows as well(although some gems are available on git to provide v8.dll and other support)

Comment: gem "therubyracer", :require => 'v8'  add this to gemfile and check

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using a Linux distribution on your Chromebook (either directly or via `chroot`). Is this correct?

It's looking for `v8.h`, so you'll need to install the v8 development package as well: it's `libv8-dev` on Debian/Ubuntu (and something `-devel` on RedHat and similar).

Comment: ah so something like apt-get install libv8-dev?